# How to integrate star (*) in the changing pattern in sed?

Tags: bash, sed, gsub

I have a `test1.txt` file with a lot of lines with different information. Among them, some lines have this kind of information:

```
Fam_grapsidae
Fam_bursidae
Fam_siluridae
```

I want to change the `Fam_*` into `italic{*}`, in order to have in `test2.txt`:

```
italic{grapsidae}
italic{bursidae}
italic{siluridae}
```

So I tried with `sed`:

```
 sed 's/Fam_*/italic{*\}/g' test1.txt > test2.txt
```

But I obtained this:

```
italic{*}grapsidae
```

So, how can I integrate stars in the `sed` command to have `italic{grapsidae}` expression ?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `\*` escape i t

Comment: @KamilCuk actually no, OP isn't searching for a literal `*` ; when he says "I want to change the Fam_* into italic{*}" the `*` refer to variable parts of text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is:

```
sed 's/Fam_\(.*\)/italic{\1}/' test1.txt > test2.txt
```

Comment: Yes, this is called a capture.  Most regex flavors allow you to capture up to 9 patterns which can be recalled with the sequences `\1` - `\9` in the replace pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Must utilize `extended regex` by `-E` option to be able get it back after capturing in group first

```
sed -E 's/Fam_(\w*)/italic{\1}/' test1.txt > test2.txt
```

Comment: `-E` affects how you capture the text not how you retrieve the captured text and you don't need it to capture text. Also, most seds won't understand what `\w` means (GNU sed only?) so YMMV with using that.